# How to use match as with Regular Expression in Mongodb with in Aggregate switch case?

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregate

Here what i did.

Inside $AddFields

```
    {
 ClientStatus:{
      $switch: {
   branches: [
      { case: {
        $eq:
        [
          "$CaseClientStatus",
           /In Progress/i              
        ]},
          then:'In Progress'
      },
      { case: {
        $eq:
        [
          "$CaseClientStatus",
          {regex:/Cancelled/i}
        ],
      },then:'Cancelled'},
      { case: {$eq:['$CaseClientStatus','Complete - All Results Clear']}, then:'Complete'},
      { case: {$eq:['$CaseClientStatus','Case on Hold']}, then:'Case on Hold'}
   ],
   default: 'Other'
}}
}
```

but with this my ClientStatus is showing only Complete,Other,Case On Hold not the one with specified with regex. alghough field contains those words.

here is the one of the doc

```
{
  "CandidateName": "Bruce  Consumer",  
  "_id": "61b30daeaa237672bb7a17cc",
  "CaseClientStatus": "Background Check Case In Progress",
  "TAT": "N/A",
  "CaseCloseDate": null,
  "FormationAutomationStatus": "Automated",
  "MethodOfDataSupply": "Automated",
  "Status": "Background Case In Progress",
  "CreatedDate": "2021-12-10T08:19:58.389Z",  
  "OrderId": "Ord3954",
  "PONumber": "",
  "Position": "",
  "FacilityCode": "",
  "IsCaseClose": false,
  "Requester": "Shah Shah",
  "ReportErrorList": 0
}
```

Comment: Please post the input doc that you believe should match Cancelled or In Progress.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I did update the question with  Input Doc that suppose to be match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on version 4.2 or higher (and you should be because 4.2 came out almost 2 years ago) then the `$regexFind` function gives you what you need.  Prior to 4.2, regex was only available in a `$match` operator, not in complex agg expressions.  Your attempt above is admirable but the `//` regex syntax is *not* doing what you think it should be doing.  Notably, `{regex:/Cancelled/i}` is simply creating a new object with key `regex` and string value `/Cancelled/i` (including the slashes) which clearly will not equal anything in `$CaseClientStatus`.  Here is a solution:

```
ClientStatus:{
    $switch: {
      branches: [
         { case: {
            $ne: [null, {$regexFind: {input: "$CaseClientStatus", regex: /In Progress/i}}]
           }, then:'In Progress'},
         { case: {
            $ne: [null, {$regexFind: {input: "$CaseClientStatus", regex: /Cancelled/i}}]
           },then:'Cancelled'},
         { case: {$eq:['$CaseClientStatus','Complete - All Results Clear']}, then:'Complete'},
         { case: {$eq:['$CaseClientStatus','Case on Hold']}, then:'Case on Hold'}
      ],
      default: 'Other'
}}
```

It looks like you are trying to take a somewhat free-form status "description" field and create a strong enumerated status from it.  I would recommend that your `$ClientStatus` output be more code-ish e.g. `IN_PROGRESS, COMPLETE, CXL` etc.  Eliminate case and certainly whitespace.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i did able to solve the query but using $regexMatch  instead of $regexFind as its take cares of null. thanks by the way i was not aware about this two new addition as i did work 3 years ago on mongo and again working on another project after 3 years.

Comment: @NisargDesai  Don't be shy about hitting the upvote arrow.   :-)